# Upload model ImageField with DjangoREST + Angular

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I new in REST and trying to create simple app, with one model and two fields `CharField`, `ImageField`.
model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):

    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', max_length=254)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
```

serializers:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('img','text')
```

views:

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

photo_router = DefaultRouter()
photo_router.register(r'photo', PhotoViewSet)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(photo_router.urls)),]
```

POST and GET works well in `/api/photo/`
I ask similar question before and I was definitely sure, problem was in frontend, with AngularJS, I using AngularJS first time too. But I think now, maybe problem with my server app.
angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularFileUpload']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/angular/templates/home.html'
    })
});
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

GET controller works well, I recieve all my images:

```
app.controller('getController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/api/photo/').success(function(data){
        $scope.photos = data;
    }).error(function(data) {
        $scope.photos = data;
    });
}]);
```

For file uploading I used [this guide](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)
Here is code from guide:

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope,     fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/api/photo/";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

html code:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

When I upload files by this form I have:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo/ 400 (Bad Request)
>   in responce:
>   img: ["No file was submitted."]

Please help at least to understand, where my problem is, on my REST or in Angular. And how I can debug this? I spend all day for trying find solution. I think I just clearly don't understand how REST api need to looks.
**UPD**
I'm trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#install) and still have 400 responce status.
I decide is problem with serializer, I overide POST method in view, but I think I did it wrong:

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,  status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is full request data from web tool:

> **General**
>           Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo/
>           Request Method:POST
>           Status Code:400 Bad Request
>           Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
>       **Response Headers**
>           Allow:GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
>           Content-Type:application/json
>           Date:Wed, 09 Mar 2016 14:46:44 GMT
>           Server:WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
>           Vary:Accept, Cookie
>           X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
>       **Request Headers**
>           Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>           Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
>           Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>           Connection:keep-alive
>           Content-Length:16635
>           Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----        WebKitFormBoundarytci4JfMISlMXwzFw
>           Cookie:sessionid=f5nyqdclupgi44zyqbmo3gkenum9k0cj;             csrftoken=E0DuVDs5KrV0rSMuD5wC86RPO0QP4AgT
>           Host:127.0.0.1:8000
>           Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
>           Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>           User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>           X-CSRFToken:E0DuVDs5KrV0rSMuD5wC86RPO0QP4AgT
>       **Request Payload**
>           ------WebKitFormBoundarytci4JfMISlMXwzFw
>           Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2.jpg"
>           Content-Type: image/jpeg
>           ------WebKitFormBoundarytci4JfMISlMXwzFw--

Comment: Give this directive a try: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload
For the backend, I'd recommend using the debugger, so you can actually look into the request object.

Comment: @fodma1 you mean django-debug-toolbar? I forget about it. And I tryied ng-file-upload, I write it in question

Comment: Nope, I meant that you could run your python code in your IDE (eg. IntelliJ/Pycharm/Eclipse) and all of these have debug mode, where you can inspect the variables in each line

Comment: And you can also check your post request in Chrome dev toolbar

Comment: @fodma1 I post it in quetion, sure I check my dev toolbar. And I have responce `{"img":["No file was submitted."]}`

Comment: @Baterson Can you post your request detail also...ie full request data from Network tab of Chrome.

Comment: I think if you are sending a `FormData` in post, you need to add [MultiPartParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) in `parser_classes` in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the example provided on the page [Django Rest Framework File Upload](https://medium.com/@jxstanford/django-rest-framework-file-upload-e4bc8de669c0#.nl3v8rjly):

You will need to add relevant [`parser_classes`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#parsers) in the view and also override the `perform_create` function to get the `file` from the POST data:

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(img=self.request.data.get('img'))
        # do note that at this time `text` information is not available
```

Since, we are posting `FormData` we use following parsers ([link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser)):

```
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
```

Also, notice that `serializer.is_valid()` is throwing error because it is not getting the `img` field in the post data. You need to set `img` instead of `file` field:

```
fd.append('img', file);
```

Comment: @Baterson Did you try this approach?

Comment: thank you, I update my code, but stil same problem with 400 answer. Maybe I need to add some properties in `settings.py` for Django REST?

Comment: Is it a error with different message or with same message?

Comment: Which DRF version are you using? Can you also show the content of `request.data` on the server side?

Comment: Same  responce message `{"img":["No file was submitted."]}`. Here is in server side `"POST /api/photo/ HTTP/1.1" 400 34`. About DRF, I just install last version by `pip install djangorestframework`

Comment: I didn't mean this. I meant the content of `request.data` in `perform_create` function. Can you print it and update the question?

Comment: I tried, but it printed only in `/api/photo/` in default Django REST debugger, when I upload by angular, nothing hapend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105823/discussion-between-aks-and-baterson).